# Style Transfer in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I am having trouble understanding the way that the content and style filters are being trained for (e.g.  [in this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1508.06576) ) in style transfer algorithms using TensorFlow.
I have examined a few implementations of the algorithm in the linked paper, but I can't quite grok their treatment of this step. To that end, I thought it would be to helpful implement a naive version, without using the pre-trained model. My understanding of the steps involved are:

1. Train a CNN on a single image (in the paper they use the pre-trained VGG network)
2. Using the trained network, feed in a white noise image. Define a new loss function that is minimized by updating the input image (this is how the image is 'painted') e.g. 'content' is derived by minimizing the distance between the conv layers in the trained model, and those resulting from the input (white noise) image

Thus, the implementation should be something like:

```
import TensorFlow as tf

x_in = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, num_pixels], name='x')
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, num_pixels], name='y')

...

diff = y_-y_out
loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.abs(diff))  # minimizing 'pixel difference'
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(loss)
# training model
for i in range(NUM_TRAINING_STEPS):
    _, loss_val = sess.run([train_step, loss], 
                           feed_dict={x_in: input_image, y_: input_image})
```

After training the model, I can generate a white noise image, but how can I used the trained model to update my input image? My suspicion is that I need to create a second network, where `x_in` is of type `tf.Variable` and load the weights and biases from the trained model, but the details of this elude me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you could store your input image in a tf.Variable, load the weights from the trained model, and run an optimization loop with the style transfer loss function wrt to the input variable.

Answer (score 0):

you can just use a style transfer as a service site to train styles like http://somatic.io